# Query count from selected data in join table

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

I am trying to get all combinations of product_categories and filters with also the count of filters selected for each product.

I can get the combinations, but I am having trouble to then get the right count.
I am working in Laravel and using a \DB::raw Query.

This is what I have got so far:

```
\DB::raw("SELECT product_categories.*,filters.name as filter, filter_types.heading as filter_type
                FROM product_categories, filters
                JOIN filter_types ON filter_types.id = filters.filter_type_id
                WHERE filter_types.type = 'Modules\\\DonaldRussell\\\ProductCategories\\\App\\\ProductCategory'
                ORDER BY product_categories.name, filter_type
                ");
```

The db schema is as follow:

```
Schema::create('filter_types', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('type')->notNull();
        $table->string('heading')->notNull();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

Schema::create('filters', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('filter_type_id')->unsigned()->notNull();
        $table->foreign('filter_type_id')->references('id')->on('categories_types');
        $table->string('name')->notNull();
        $table->integer('order')->notNull();
        $table->integer('uses')->unsigned()->notNull()->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });

Schema::create('product_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->notNull();
        $table->string('slug')->notNull();
        $table->integer('order')->notnull()->unsigned()->default(0);
        $table->integer('type')->notnull()->unsigned()->default(1);
        $table->integer('seo')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('seo')->references('id')->on('seos')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

Schema::create('product_category_sets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('product_categories')->onDelete('set null');
        $table->integer('sub_category_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('sub_category_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('set null');
        $table->integer('sub_sub_category_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('sub_sub_category_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('set null');
        $table->integer('product_id')->notnull()->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

Schema::create('product_category_set_filters', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('product_category_set_id')->notnull()->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('product_category_set_id')->references('id')->on('product_category_sets')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('filter_id')->notnull()->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('filter_id')->references('id')->on('filters')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

In the screenshot below see the result I need without the count column that I can't get to work:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i dont think your structure is correct, but let's suppose it is.

We need 4 models:
`ProductCategorySet::class`,
`Product::class`,
`Category::class`(product_category),
and `Filter::class`.

With the proper relations between them, you will be able to do

```
ProductCategorySet::with('product')->with('category')->withCount('filters')->get();
```

and that would be all you need.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProductCategorySet extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function filters()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Filter::class, 'product_category_set_filters', 'product_category_set_id', 'filter_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: I have posted a picture of the result i need.

Comment: @Marco have you tried the solution i proposed ? Cause using `DB::raw()` in an ORM environment is not recommended. your code will be un-maintainable.

Comment: Yes and it doesn't work. I got the result with a union  query in the ed.

Comment: the `FROM product_categories, filters` makes you results arbitrary (false).